# Trying to use dice coef loss function with images of int16

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

I'm using Python 3.7.7. and Tensorflow 2.3.0.

When I try to use this loss function:

```
def dice_coef(y_true, y_pred):
    y_true_f = K.flatten(y_true)
    y_pred_f = K.flatten(y_pred)
    intersection = K.sum(y_true_f * y_pred_f)
    return (2 * intersection + 1) // (K.sum(y_true_f) + K.sum(y_pred_f) + 1)

def dice_coef_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    return 1-dice_coef(y_true, y_pred)
```

With U-Net:

```
model.compile(tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=(1e-4) * 2), loss=dice_coef_loss, metrics=['accuracy'])
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-25-91bea884e0c8> in <module>()
----> 1 results = model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=4, epochs=50, validation_data=(X_valid, y_valid))

            10 frames

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    971           except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
    972             if hasattr(e, "ag_error_metadata"):
--> 973               raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
    974             else:
    975               raise

TypeError: in user code:

    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:806 train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    <ipython-input-19-deec0ad5082f>:8 dice_coef_loss  *
        return 1-dice_coef(y_true, y_pred)
    <ipython-input-24-8de47985e665>:4 dice_coef  *
        intersection = K.sum(y_true_f * y_pred_f)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py:1141 binary_op_wrapper
        raise e
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py:1125 binary_op_wrapper
        return func(x, y, name=name)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py:1457 _mul_dispatch
        return multiply(x, y, name=name)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py:201 wrapper
        return target(*args, **kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py:509 multiply
        return gen_math_ops.mul(x, y, name)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_math_ops.py:6176 mul
        "Mul", x=x, y=y, name=name)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py:506 _apply_op_helper
        inferred_from[input_arg.type_attr]))

    TypeError: Input 'y' of 'Mul' Op has type float32 that does not match type int16 of argument 'x'.
```

Any idea about how to fix it?

I have also tried with this version:

```
def dice_coef(y_true, y_pred):
    y_true_f = K.flatten(y_true)
    y_pred_f = K.flatten(y_pred)
    intersection = K.sum(y_true_f * y_pred_f)
    return (2.0 * intersection + 1.0) / (K.sum(y_true_f) + K.sum(y_pred_f) + 1.0)

def dice_coef_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    return 1-dice_coef(y_true, y_pred)
```

But I get the same error.

Comment: What if you cast y_true to float32?

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy Now it works. Thanks.